# What is the meaning of the magnitudes on the axes of this spectrum?

Tags: radiation, spectroscopy

I'm taking a course on radiation physics and I've been given an spectrum by my professor (concretely it is a spectrum of $\left.^{22} Na \right.$). This is the first time that I come across this kind of spectrums and I have no idea on how to understand the meaning of the magnitudes depicted.

This is the spectrum:

[image]

I understand that the Y-axis is the energy, so the energy of each peak can be read off from this, but I have no clue about the X-axis. What is its meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x-axis is labeled as pulse height, which means the height of the electronic signal produced by the detector. This is proportional to the energy of the detected photon; a more energetic photon will produce a larger signal. The y-axis is labeled N(E) dE, which means number of events recorded within a range dE of energy E. So the height of the curve tells you how many photons were detected at a given energy. The peaks correspond to the various discrete photon energies emitted by the source.